# Xcode ERROR: Communications with Apple failed. You are not allowed to perform this operation. when I hav e

Tags: xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'm using Automatically manage signing but still I get errors:

> Communications with Apple failed.
>
> You are not allowed to perform this operation.
>
> Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further
> assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be either an Account holder, Admin or App Manager. Otherwise you won't be able to create profiles even if you select 'Automatically manage signing'.

See the permissions from App store connect:
[image]

Only 'Download Provisioning profiles' is allowed.

Having that said from roles from defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/), it indicates that development profiles are allowed. But a colleague of mine was still getting the errors mentioned. So either I'm not understanding something or there's a discrepancy in the docs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue after adding my Apple Team account and enabling automatic code signing. Despite this, the error persisted. To resolve it, I took the following steps:

1. Cleaned the build folder of my project.
2. Removed the derived data folder from my Mac.
3. Generated the archive build again.

Following these steps successfully resolved the issue for me.